# Eliminating unitialized values in my Perl hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, string, perl, hash

I successfully create a hash of arrays, and I am using it to calculate log-odds scores for each DNA sequence from a file ([Creating a hash of arrays for DNA sequences, Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316872/creating-a-hash-of-arrays-for-dna-sequences-perl) has input file format). I get a score for each sequence, but I get a warning for each calculation. Naturally, I want to clear up the warning. The warning is: `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at line 148`.

Here is a summarized version of the code (I can post the full code if necessary):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#USER SPECIFICATIONS
print "Please enter the filename of the fasta sequence data: ";
my $filename1 = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $filename1;

#Open the file and store each dna seq in hash
my %id2seq = ();
my %HoA = ();
my %loscore = ();
my $id = '';
open (FILE, '<', $filename1) or die "Cannot open $filename1.",$!;
my $dna;
while (<FILE>)
{
    if($_ =~ /^>(.+)/)
    {
         $id = $1; #Stores 'Sequence 1' as the first $id, for example
    }
    else
    {
        $HoA{$id} = [ split(//) ]; #Splits the contents to allow for position reference later
        $id2seq{$id} .= $_; #Creates a hash with each seq associated to an id number, used for calculating tables that have been omitted for space
        $loscore{$id} .= 0; #Creates a hash with each id number to have a log-odds score
    }
}
close FILE;

#User specifies motif width
print "Please enter the motif width:\n";
my $width = <STDIN>;

#Remove newline from file
chomp $width;

#Default width is 3 (arbitrary number chosen)
if ($width eq '')
{
    $width = 3;
}

#Omitting code about $width<=0, creation of log-odds score hash to save space

foreach $id (keys %HoA, %loscore)
{
    for my $pos (0..($width-1))
    {
        for my $base (qw( A C G T))
        {
            if ($HoA{$id}[$pos] eq $base) #ERROR OCCURS HERE
            {
                $loscore{$id} += $logodds{$base}[$pos];
            }
            elsif ( ! defined $HoA{$id}[$pos]) 
            {
                print "$pos\n"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
print Dumper(\%loscore);
```

The output I get is:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at line 148, <STDIN> line 2.
2
(This error repeats 4 times for each position - most likely due to matching to each $base?)

$VAR1 = {
         'Sequence 15' => '-1.27764697876093',
         'Sequence 4' => '0.437512962981119',
         (continues for 29 sequences)
        }
```

To summarize, I want to calculate the log-odds score of each sequence. I have a log-odds score hash `%loscore` that contains the score of a base at each location within a motif. The log-odds score is calculated by summing the referenced values. For example, if the log-odds table was

```
A 4 3 2
C 7 2 1
G 6 9 2
T 1 0 3
```

The log-odds score of the sequence `CAG` would be `7+3+2=12`.

At the moment, I believe that the error occurs because of the way I split the strings of DNA to be put into the hash of arrays. As I previously stated, if you want all the code so you can copy-paste, I can provide it. I think the solution is pretty simple, and I just need someone to point me in the right direction. Any and all help is appreciated, and I can clarify as questions arise. Also, any tips that could help me to post more concise questions are appreciated (I know this one is lengthy, I just want to provide enough background information).

Comment: This statement looks a little bit suspect: `foreach $id (keys %HoA, %loscore)`. Why do you only take the keys of the first hash?

Comment: Should be `foreach $id (keys %HoA)`

Comment: I was apparently wrong with the format. I changed to `foreach $id (keys %HoA, keys %loscore)`, and it works perfectly now! Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: `foreach $id (keys %HoA, keys %loscore)` is the same thing as `foreach $id (keys %HoA, keys %HoA)`. Are you sure you want to loop through every key twice?

Comment: Nit: `$loscore{$id} .= 0;` should be `$loscore{$id} = 0;`, and it should be in the "then" part of the `if`, not the "else" parse.

Comment: I think I want to loop through the keys twice. This is because I have the same keys for both hashes. Correct me if there is a better / more correct way to do this.

Comment: If you still want to loop for each key twice, then there is indeed a better way. Replace `foreach $id (keys %HoA, keys %loscore) { ... $loscore{$id} += $logodds{$base}[$pos]; ... }` with `foreach $id (keys %HoA) { ... $loscore{$id} += $logodds{$base}[$pos] * 2; ... }`. That said, I seriously doubt you want to loop for each key twice. I think simply want `foreach $id (keys %HoA)`

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. I was under the impression that I needed to have the other hashes included in the `foreach` statement to use them. `foreach $id (keys %HoA)` works great!

Comment: If you have a solution, please answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I am using to iterate through the `%HoA. It calculates a log-odds score for each sequence, then works through each sequence to find a maximum score for each sequence. Big thanks to everyone for helping out!

```
foreach $id (keys %HoA)
{
    for my $pos1 (0..length($HoA{$id})-1)
    {
        for my $pos2 ($pos1..$pos1+($width-1))
        {
            for my $base (qw( A C G T))
            {
                if ($HoA{$id}[$pos2] eq $base)
                {
                    for my $pos3 (0..$width-1)
                    {
                        $loscore{$id} += $logodds{$base}[$pos3];

                        if ($loscore{$id} > $maxscore{$id})
                        {
                            $maxscore{$id} = $loscore{$id};
                        }
                    }
                }
                elsif ( ! defined $HoA{$id}[$pos2])
                {
                    print "$pos2\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```